# how to connect turbo c/c++ program to database

Tags: c++, c, database, ms-access, turbo-c++

I want to connect Turbo C or Turbo C++ program with any database like MS Access / SQL-Server / Oracle / MySQL.

If any body know then please tell me and also give source code for it?

Comment: I am a student and want to increase my knowledge.

Comment: You won't do it with Turbo c++ - use a modern (and free) environment and compiler like codeblocks at http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: 10 years back I requested our college lab to install VC++ instead of turbo C++. They said they cant because turbo c++ is part of the curiculum. The situation has not changed in the last 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

SQLAPI++: http://www.sqlapi.com/

Answer (score 1):

http://c-ds-programs.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-can-we-connect-to-database-using-cc.html

Its possible to connect database in turbo c++..just view above link.